# Second cousins or double second cousins?

Tags: relationship-analysis, double-cousins

My parents share a set of first cousins but don’t share any common ancestors. I then share four great grandparents with my second cousins. Would they be considered my second cousins or double second cousins? Am I related to them to the same degree as my first cousins?

Here’s a little more detail:
My maternal grandmother's sister married my paternal grandmother's brother. Their children are both of my parents' first cousins on each of their mother's sides. So I’m related to this set of second cousins through both of my grandmothers. What would they be considered?